# Coaxial cable in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw a coaxial cable using `pgfplots`. It more or less *has* to be done within that program because in my document, I also want to add some 3D plot next to the cable. (I guess a solution using pure `TikZ` could also be used, but it has to use the `pgfplots` coordinates for the aforementioned reasion).

I use the below code with the result following it. You can more or less see the problem: The inner cable appears on top of the outer one. Writing the code for the two cables in the opposite order puts the inner cable in an invisible position behind the outer one, an equally bad solution. Can someone fix this, that is, make it seem as if the inner cable is really *within* the outer one?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis equal image]

    \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,z buffer=sort,variable=\u,variable y=\v,domain=0:80, y domain=0:360] ({\u},{13*cos(\v)}, {13*sin(\v)});

    \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,z buffer=sort,variable=\u,variable y=\v,domain=0:80, y domain=0:360,colormap/cool] ({\u},{4*cos(\v)}, {4*sin(\v)});
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am sure we had this

Comment: But also using `pgfplots`?

Comment: No, usual TikZ [Drawing coaxial cables: TikZ or pstricks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207099) But that should not pe a problem? I think this is an xy-problem as we like to call it. I don't know your use case, but just as you can add *annotations to a plot* (called so in the doc) you can use another tikzpicture (`pic` in tikz v 3.0?).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible in PGFPlots. From the section in the manual titled *Before you start with 3D*: PGFPlots "cannot combine different `\addplot` commands, those will be drawn in the order of appearance". You could split the outer cable into a front and back section, and draw the inner cable between those two sections, but that's going to be very fiddly.

Comment: @Johannes_B But as mentioned, I need to draw a 3D plot of some data (to be concrete, it is a plot of the electric potential in the `z` plane). The coaxial cable is to appear above this plot to illustrate what each position corresponds to. That is why it is important to use `pgfplots`.

Comment: @Jake, it also mentions some level of layer support. Not that I understood anything from that section at all.

Comment: @Gaussler: The layer support makes it possible to put different graphic elements (like grid lines, plots and labels) in different orders, but sadly, it doesn't overcome the limitation that each `\addplot` command is drawn in a separate layer.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. :-(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can split the outer cable as suggested by Jake.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis equal image]

       \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,z buffer=sort,variable=\u,variable y=\v,domain=0:80,
                    y domain=-90:90] ({\u},{13*cos(\v)}, {13*sin(\v)});
       \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,z buffer=sort,variable=\u,variable y=\v,domain=0:80,
                    y domain=0:360,colormap/cool] ({\u},{4*cos(\v)}, {4*sin(\v)});
       \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,z buffer=sort,variable=\u,variable y=\v,domain=0:80,
                    y domain=90:270] ({\u},{13*cos(\v)}, {13*sin(\v)});
    \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `hide axis`:

[image]

Comment: Ah, not too fiddly at all. Nice!